# How to access settings of new Skype for linux to set proxy?

Tags: 17.04, skype, proxy

I am unable to access settings from tools in the new Skype. I am using ubuntu 17.04. I need it to set proxy which it is not automatically set. I have to set proxy along with username and authentication.

Answer (score 2):

**Skype for Linux Beta** has a **basic** support for the system HTTPS proxy.

Configure it via environment property `HTTPS_PROXY`, using the following format:

```
https_proxy = http(s)://username:password@hostname:port
```

---

#### Workaround:

I'm using Skype **web version** and works fine with proxy setting directly in the browser:

- https://web.skype.com/

---

> **Conclusion:** Microsoft blocks the proxy configuration in **Linux**.
>
> The main motivation for do this it's force companies pay for **Skype for Business** (SfB).

---

> **UPDATE: [Skype for Business Online - End of Life - July 31, 2021](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/skype-for-business-online-end-of-life-july-31-2021/ba-p/779137)**
>
> The replacement will be **Microsoft Teams** in an attempt to fix Skype problems and limitations.

---

#### References:

- https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa1017/can-i-connect-to-skype-through-a-proxy-server
- https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34656/more-information-about-skype-for-linux-beta
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_signms/configure-skype-proxy-on-linux/f7f4eaed-b2c0-47d6-8168-eef7b444b081